# How do I make duplicity upload to MEGA?

Tags: backup, mega

In unity settings, you have a `Backups` option, there you can choose from `Storage Locations`: `FTP`, `SSH`, `WebDAV`, `Windows Share`, `Custom Location`, `Local Folder`. Way back there was an option there to backup to the Ubuntu One(Cloud Storage). I'm looking for something similar to upload to MEGA.

I tried all of the aforementioned options, to backup to the site `https://mega.co.nz/`, but no luck. I also tried via command line using duplicity:

```
duplicity /home/USERNAME/MEGAsync/ mega://USERNAME:PASSWORD@mega.co.nz/MEGAsync
```

But, I'm greeted with an error message:

> BackendException: Error while authenticating client: -9.

I already installed mega.py:

```
sudo pip install mega.py
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mega.py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mega.py)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from mega.py)
Cleaning up...
```

I also tried this in a clean install Virtualbox machine just in case something is interfering. But after installing mega.py, and rebooting, I still get the above error.

---

How do I use MEGA as my Cloud Backup Storage, via the backup settings?

Tried this on :

- Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04.2, Duplicity 0.6.23, mega.py 0.9.18

  - Error:
  - > BackendException: Error while authenticating client: -9.
- Ubuntu Vivid Vervet 15.04, Duplicity 0.7.01, mega.py 0.9.18

  - Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/bin/duplicity",
>   line 1500, in 
>       with_tempdir(main)
>    File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1494, in with_tempdir
>       fn()
>    File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1327, in main
>       action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line
>   1055, in ProcessCommandLine
>       backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 948,
>   in set_backend
>       globals.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 221, in
>   get_backend
>       obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 207, in
>   get_backend_object
>       return factory(pu)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/megabackend.py",
>   line 44, in **init**
>       self.__authorize(parsed_url.username, self.get_password())
>    File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/megabackend.py",
>   line 104, in __authorize
>       self.client.login(email, password)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mega/mega.py", line 31, in
>   login
>       self._login_user(email, password)
>    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mega/mega.py", line 42, in
>   _login_user
>       raise RequestError(resp)
>  RequestError: -9

Comment: Did you use an @ symbol in the username? Have you tried %40 in place of the @ symbol?

Comment: @gardnerbickford I used the @ symbol, and will try the %40, when I get the chance to.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @paf.goncalves No. Unfortunately. This is a bug: [Bug #1475579 “duplicity crashes when trying to connect to MEGA” : Bugs : duplicity package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1475579)

Comment: My problem was i was using the wrong email :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've solvedthe login problem of duplicity on mega with these steps:

I've create the `.megarc` file in my *$HOME*

```
[Login]
Username = myuser@mydomain.com
Password = the-relative-password
```

see [megarc (5) manual](https://megatools.megous.com/man/megarc.html)

Then I call duplicity with fake user:

```
duplicity my_local_dir mega://myuser@mega.nz/MEGA_REMOTE_DIR
```

duplicity check the existence of `.megarc` and ignore the login params.
Unfortunately the login params is expexted (at the release 7.16) and if it miss duplicity make a mess with path calculations.